# jQuery Flotcharts - straight series line ending on a datapoint

Tags: javascript, jquery, plot, flot

I'm having problems with the formatting of the following flot chart:

[image]

I want my second series (gray) straight, just as square. It should start from 682 and end in 683. How to solve it?

Options for my flot:

```
var options = {
        grid: {
            clickable: true,
            hoverable: true 
        },
        series: {
            lines: {
                show: true,
                fill: true,
                lineWidth: 0,
                fillColor: { colors: [{opacity: 1 }, { opacity: 1}] },

            },

        },
        colors: ["rgba(41, 150, 206, 0.9)", "rgba(67, 90, 110, 0.4)",],
        crosshair: {
            mode: "xy",
            color: "#323232",
            lineWidth: 1,
        },
        xaxis: {
            mode: mode,
            show: true,
            position: "bottom",
            color: "#323232",
            font: {
                size: 10,
                lineHeight: 15,
            },
            labelHeight: 15,
        },
        yaxis: {
            show: true,
            position: "left",
            color: "#323232",
            labelWidth: 20,
            font: {
                size: 10,
            },
            max: 150,
            min: 0,
        },
        pan: {
            interactive: true,
            cursor: "move",
            frameRate: 60,
        },
        tooltip: true,
        tooltipOpts: {
            id:             'flotTip',                 
            content:        '%x : %y km/h',      
            shifts: {
                x:          10,                    
                y:          20,                    
            },
            defaultTheme:   true,                 
            lines: {
                track:      false,                 
                threshold:  0.05,                  
            },

        }
    };
```

Comment: How can we give solution from image, without showing your code?

Comment: Has your series values of zero outside the 682 to 683 range? If so, replace them with `null`.

Comment: Its working with null, thanks.

Comment: I added an answer with a little more explanation. Please accept/upvote it if you find it helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have zero values outside the range where your data has non-zero values the graph will connect those (valid) datapoints with diagonal lines. If you want to end the graph at a  specific point change the values after that point to `null`.

This is described in the [documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md#data-format):

> If a null is specified as a point or if one of the coordinates is null or couldn't be converted to a number, the point is ignored when drawing. As a special case, a null value for lines is interpreted as a line segment end, i.e. the points before and after the null value are not connected.